# Understanding Nested Joins

Tags: mysql, join, nested

I've came across nested joins, which logic I cannot understand.

Names of tables are not important, query from which I extracted this - works.

```
FROM
    (((sea
    JOIN bold)
    JOIN ((genuine
    LEFT JOIN community_genuine_inspire ON (genuine.id = community_genuine_inspire.id_genuine))
    LEFT JOIN community_genuine ON (community_genuine.id = community_genuine_inspire.id_community)))
    JOIN cooperate)
WHERE
```

There were used a lot of parentheses and JOIN shorthands and the question is - how should I "decode" this to the standard JOIN syntax avoiding all those shorthands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no nesting here. Parenthesis have been dropped here and there to obfuscate the code, which is basically equivalent to:

```
select *
FROM sea
JOIN bold
JOIN genuine
LEFT JOIN community_genuine_inspire ON genuine.id = community_genuine_inspire.id_genuine
LEFT JOIN community_genuine ON community_genuine.id = community_genuine_inspire.id_community
JOIN cooperate
```

Is the `ON` clause optional? Yes, it is. It's what [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) refer to as `join_specification` and is shown in brackets, documentation syntax that means *optional*:

```
joined_table: {
    table_reference {[INNER | CROSS] JOIN | STRAIGHT_JOIN} table_factor [join_specification]
  | table_reference {LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER] JOIN table_reference join_specification
  | table_reference NATURAL [INNER | {LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER]] JOIN table_factor
}

join_specification: {
    ON search_condition
  | USING (join_column_list)
}
```

If you omit it I presume you get a `CROSS JOIN` (Cartesian product).